# Binary code in kern.log and

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, syslog, crash-dumps

We had one of our servers crashed this morning, for the second time in two weeks. Before that, it ran for months withoug issues, and afaik, no changes were made.

What's strange is that there are some strange characters in kern.log and syslog, which appears to be some representation of binary code. If I grep for 'error', I get 'binay file matches', although these files should be plain text I believe.

Any ideas what might be happening or how to investigate this? hardware failure/security/... We run Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

The machine was responsive up to about 11 AM, and rebooted around 11.30 so there is a part of the log missing as well.

*Example from kern.log.*

`Sep 26 07:38:42 biominas002 kernel: [918855.467235] device vnet1 entered promiscuous mode
Sep 26 07:38:42 biominas002 kernel: [918855.479364] br0: port 3(vnet1) entered forwarding state
Sep 26 07:38:42 biominas002 kernel: [918855.479370] br0: port 3(vnet1) entered forwarding state
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
.....
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Sep 26 11:23:37 biominas002 kernel: imklog 5.8.6, log source = /proc/kmsg started.`

*Example from syslog (does not show the logging gap):*

`Sep 26 10:51:30 biominas002 rpc.mountd[1942]: authenticated mount request from 143.169.238.125:667 for /home (/home)
Sep 26 10:53:54 biominas002 rpc.mountd[1942]: authenticated unmount request from 143.169.238.151:878 for /home (/home)
Sep 26 10:56:20 biominas002 rpc.mountd[1942]: authenticated unmount request from 143.169.238.120:879 for /home (/home)
Sep 26 10:59:11 biominas002 rpc.mountd[1942]: authenticated mount request from 143.169.238.120:731 for /home (/home)
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
......
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Sep 26 11:23:37 biominas002 kernel: imklog 5.8.6, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Sep 26 11:23:37 biominas002 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="1722" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Sep 26 11:23:37 biominas002 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 103`

Comment: Did you figure this out? We have similar issues on BeagleBone